# address information

Tags: address

a person is trying to get me to transfer 500.00 in bitcoin to an address. The address doesn't have any balance, known input, repeated input, tags, or website appearances, total received, last known ouptput, repeated output. To me this is fraudulent since there is no history of bitcoin activity with this individual. Am I being too paranoid.? thanks for your help. new here,lol

Answer (score 3):

You can never understand someone's trustworthiness by looking at their balance history.

It's common to use a new address to receive a new transaction every time. This may be to make it harder for a customer to see another customer's balance or more importantly, understand who sent them money (for example, 2 people buy the same thing costing $500, while you have received $500 only once)